# PhpStorm run file in browser

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm and WAMP.

My project location is: `C:\!Dev_Web\PHP\PHP_test` where I have a file `test1.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The wamp location is: `C:\wamp` (port 80)

When I run the file I see the results in run window.

How to display the results in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may copy your files to the directory **C:\wamp\www**, and to acess your project in your browser acess the page **localhost/projectfilename/test1.php**

Answer (score 2):

You can setup deployment to local folder and this will be simply a matter of saving the file.

Steps:
1) In PhpStorm open `Tools -> Deployment ->` Tick `Automatic Upload (always)`. This way your file will be copied to desired directory every time you save the file.

2) `Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration`

3) in the window opened click + button and, enter any name, f.e. 'Test Folder' and in the dropdown `Type` select `Local or mounted folder`

4) After that click select folder `C:\wamp` in the `Folder` field on the right side and enter server address.

5) on the tab `Mappings` in the right section enter `Deployment path on server` as \ or select whatever path you want relative to `c:\wamp`. Your edited file will be copied there upon save.

6) On the left side tick button `Use Default` (4th next to `+` button)

7) Click `Ok`. That's it.

Now, you don't have to copy file manually each time. Just edit, save and it will be copied automatically. If you want to copy it manually with keyboard shortcut - just set shortcut for action `Upload to Default Server` (I personally set it to `Ctrl+Alt+U`) and untick `Automatic Upload`.

Answer (score 0):

right click on file, `open file 'file name' on local` or direct by browser `http://localhost/projectname/filename.php`

Answer (score 0):

you need to run your file from URL, not from PhpStorm.
like: "localhost\module\file.php"
otherwise you need to setup on PhpStorm

Comment: configure inerpreter. and you need to just add the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Jonathan Felipe da Rosa said you need to copy  the files to wamp WWW, from this you should be able to right click on the wamp icon in your task bar and select localhost.